# How did Saraswati end up as "wife" of Brahma?

Tags: vedas, puranas, brahma, sin, saraswati

According to [Shatapatha Brahmana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63143.html), Brahma conceives a passion for his own daughter but the gods condemn Brahma, even the goddess goes away from Brahma.

> 1. Prajāpati conceived a passion for his own daughter,--either the Sky or the Dawn. 'May I pair with her!' thus
>      (thinking) he united with her.
> 2. This, assuredly, was a sin in the eyes of the gods. 'He who acts thus towards his own daughter, our sister, [commits a sin],' they
>      thought.
> 3. The gods then said to this god who rules over the beasts (Rudra), 'This one, surely, commits a sin who acts thus towards his
>      own daughter, our sister. Pierce him!' Rudra, taking aim, pierced him.
>      Half of his seed fell to the ground. And thus it came to pass.

When the gods and goddess herself were against Brahma and his lust then how did Saraswati end up as a wife of Brahma? Is there some explanation in any Veda Purana?
Why is there this discrepancy in this story, it is akin to a deer which runs away from hunter but then comes back to get killed under the hands of that very same hunter.  This story doesn't make sense.

Also do Vedas really say that Saraswati is married "wife" of Brahma? Which Veda says that?

Is she married wife or consort/companion as some other people say?
How can gods allow such sin when they were against it the first time?

What is their actual relation? The dharam shastras place very harsh punishment for incest then how did Brahma get away with this sin?

How can people even accept that saraswati is wife of his own father?

Comment: first of all its Prajapati not Pragapati. Then to answer, Saraswati, Ganga  , Lakshmi were wives of Vishnu. One day in a fight Saraswati cursed Ganga to be river, Ganga also cursed Saraswati to be river. Lakshmi stood quiet in fight, so Saraswati cursed her also that you did not help me so you also become a river. Knowing this fight, Vishnu told Saraswati to be wife of Brahma, Ganga to be wife of Shiva, and Lakshmi to remain with Him. This story is in Brahma Vaivarta and Devi Puraan

Comment: @AnuragSingh yeah, my question is related to vedas though ;)

Comment: @AnuragSingh so, you mean first she was not wife when she was conceived but later became vishnu's wife then brahma's wife?

Comment: Devi Puraana and Brahma Vaivarta tell that Saraswati came out from body of Raadhika. Then Saraswati wanted to marry Krishna. But Krishna told that I am one with Radhika only, so you be wife of Vishnu , Vishnu has incarnated from Me, so He is same as me. Then Saraswati became wife of Vishnu and later the above incident happened. While mention of Brahma lusting for Saraswati is in Devi Puraana, but no mention of Saraswati being born of Brahma. So who knows how Saraswati manifested - from Radhika or from Brahma

Comment: @AnuragSingh I have hard time believing in that. The wedding of shiva-Parvati and laxmi Vishnu is described in such lengthy way, why doesn't brahma's? The story of Brahma saraswati everywhere seems so hush hush, neither does it mention how did saraswati agree to it?

Comment: yes you're right. Somewhere Saraswati is born of Brahma, somewhere She has come out of Radhika, somewhere MahaKali created Saraswati , and Shiva and MahaLakshmi created Brahma and Lakshmi and, then MahaLakshmi gave Saraswati to Brahma.

Comment: @AnuragSingh puranas are confusing, I always end up questioning my faith because of them.

Comment: Yes, Same here. Puraanas have many decrepamcies . We do not know if today's Puraanas are even authentic or not. When I read some story in one Puraana, I have too check other Puraanas too to see if the story is even authentic or not.

Comment: Which looks discrepancies on the surface are actually due to Kalpa-Bheda. In one Kalpa, something happened, in another something else.

Comment: @Rohit. I still want to know, this thing is confusing me, how did she end up as "patni" of brahma, how can gods allow it?

Comment: @Anisha Brahma is creator. They would have turned out to be daughters of Brahma whoever he would marry. Another case is some acts are bound to happen - which is Niyati. The dualistic world can't be perfect as perfection exists only in realm of duality. But in any case, whoever is wrong is wrong be it Brahma. Remember Brahma is the creator who did so. Whatever be the religion of anyone is, the truth about creator won't change. So this is not a problem of our scriptures this is a fact of creator. We say what happened.

Comment: @Rohit. But how did gods allowed it when they were against it the first time?

Comment: @Anisha don't know. Maybe someone made them understand - just a guess.

Comment: The best way we can explain Kalpa bheda is using the following statement. "Mr x won elections and became president" and then "Mr x lost elections and is not the president". Both the things have happened but not in the same election but in different election terms

Answer (score 2):

First let us understand that the concept of time in our puranas is Cyclical. So there are lot of Lord brahmas before the current period and there will be lot more after this.

The best reference we will get from puranas is from Srimad bhagavatam

SB 3.12.30

> naitat pūrvaiḥ kṛtaṁ tvad ye
>
> na kariṣyanti cāpare
>
> yas tvaṁ duhitaraṁ gaccher
>
> anigṛhyāṅgajaṁ prabhuḥ

The current act that you are trying to perform is never done before by any other Brahma.

Once realising the mistake he has committed after speaking with his sons Brahma left the body he is occupying right now.

> sa itthaṁ gṛṇataḥ putrān
>
> puro dṛṣṭvā prajāpatīn
>
> prajāpati-patis tanvaṁ
>
> tatyāja vrīḍitas tadā
>
> tāṁ diśo jagṛhur ghorāṁ
>
> nīhāraṁ yad
>   vidus tamaḥ

Lord brahma left the body and it turned into dangerous fog in all darkness.

Now as again the creation process should continue uninterrupted Lord Brahma appeared from Narayana to aide the universe.

Matha Saraswati, the creation of previous Lord Brahma became wife of current Lord Brahma and whole universe went into the state that we know of now.

The moral of this whole story is that Dharma is to be followed and adhered by everyone. There are no exceptions to this and God himself adheres to it and asks us to stick to it.

Comment: I've read bhagvatam, there is no mention of saraswati of previous Brahma becoming wife of current Brahma, if he was the first Brahma to commit such mistake and was punished for it then how after that did saraswati end up as wife of Brahma?

Comment: @Anisha unfortunately that needs to be inferred as the next verse of bhagavatam will immediately move onto time brahma created vedas. This implies that another brahma came into existence as last brahma left his body.